# Google Sheets v3 API usage limits

Tags: google-sheets-api

Although usage limits for v4 of the Google Sheets API are [clearly documented](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits), I cannot seem to find the equivalent information for v3.

To clarify the context, I have inherited a system that relies on a sheet being *published to the web* then its data retrieved in a browser, client-side via an endpoint like this: `https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/{spreadsheet ID}/1/public/values?alt=json` (no API key used)

The system is expected to come under moderate load for a short period (eg; 100,000+ hits in 24 hours) in the near future and I'm trying to work out if I need to be wary of access to the API being denied.

Thanks in advance!